# SQL error or missing database (near "DUPLICATE": syntax error

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have an SQLLITE database

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS plottokens (uuid TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, plot INTEGER DEFAULT 0, autoplot INTEGER DEFAULT 0, addon INTEGER DEFAULT 0, combination INTEGER DEFAULT 0, roadcombination INTEGER DEFAULT 0)";
```

I am trying to run

```
TokenDatabase service = TokenDatabase.getInstance();
Connection connection = service.getConnection();
String query = String.format("INSERT INTO plottokens (`uuid`, `%s`) VALUES (?, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `uuid`=?, `%s`=`%s`+1", tokenType, tokenType, tokenType);
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setString(1, uuid.toString());
preparedStatement.setString(2, uuid.toString());
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

where `tokenType` is one of a predefined set of strings, such as "plot".

This gives me `org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "DUPLICATE": syntax error)`

The intended functionality is insert with the uuid and a value of 1 if uuid doesn't exist, else increment the specified column by 1.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `on duplicate key update` is MySQL syntax, not SQLite synax.

Comment: You want what sqlite (and postgres) calls [upsert](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_upsert.html), assuming your're using a version new enough to support that syntax (3.24 or newer).

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite you must use the [`ON CONFLICT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_upsert.html) clause instead of `ON DUPLICATE KEY`.
Also there is no need to update the column `uuid`, with the same value that it already has. You only need to update the other column:

```
String query = String.format("INSERT INTO plottokens (`uuid`, `%s`) VALUES (?, 1) ON CONFLICT(`uuid`) DO UPDATE SET `%s`=`%s`+1", tokenType, tokenType, tokenType);
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setString(1, uuid.toString());
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```